# String search library in Java without the use of regex

Tags: java, string, search

I'm looking for library that is much simpler than [(Lucene in Memory search)](http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/) and serves mainly for searching within Java Strings.

It should have wildcard - AND - OR support, case sensitivity option , hit count, index of each search hit within the string; Pretty much your average search options that are used the most. Nothing special; And it should have low memory usage and be fast.

Every once in while I'm doing something simple with searching and now it is starting to bother me. So I'm contemplating to write something on my own. But before I start doing that I'd like to get scoop on what is out there.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing that most people use regex for. So no, I don't think there are any non-regex solutions out there.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/75905/a-better-way-of-doing-regex

Comment: What are cons of regex for christ's sake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if this will help you, but I have just recently looking into this myself.  [This](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/java/jsp-servlets/searching/site-search/) seems to be a fairly good list of tools.